# Create heatmap in R using stat_density2d

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have several (x,y) coordinates, and each one is associated with a binary value (either 1 or 0). I want to create a heatmap showing what the probability is at each point that a given point in that location will have a 1 associated with it.

Sample data:

```
data = read.table(header=TRUE, 
text="x    y    value
7    3    0
4    5    0
3    7    1
3    6    0
4    5    1
5    6    0")
```

And so on. I can create a plot showing where the points are concentrated using the following:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=x,y=y)) + stat_density2d(aes(fill=..level..), geom="polygon")
```

But when I try to set `fill = value`, I get the following error:

```
Error in unit(tic_pos.c, "mm") : 'x' and 'units' must have length > 0
```

How do I do this?

Edit: I should add that I can easily accomplish this using `stat_summary2d` or even `geom_tile`, but it looks much more boxy and less smooth, which I want it to be.

Comment: What should the resulting plot look like? It is not clear to me how your `value` column would be used to place colors on the density polygons.

Comment: Darker color = higher average `value` in that area, or something along those lines.